# placing a div after a css ::after

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have a CSS `::after` that displays an SVG image.
I would like my container to display **after** this SVG image.
What is happening, is that the SVG is "not taking any space" so to speak, and the next DIV is being covered by the SVG .

thanks for looking into this.

```css
.overpass-info-container::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 182px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../images/curve.svg") bottom center;
  background-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

/*  finding container  */
section.finding-container {
  top: 180px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.find-agent {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.agent-profiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<!-- ***** finding container ***** -->
<section class="finding-container">
  <div class="find-agent">
    <img src="./images/search.svg" alt="search">
  </div>
  <div class="agent-profiles">
    <img src="./images/profiles.svg" alt="profiles">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please describe your question in a brief way.

Comment: Where is .overpass-info-container div?

Comment: @RevtiShah, this is the div that comes before the curve image.

Comment: But you didn't mention into the HTML. First of all, you have to mention div.

Comment: So why not adding margin-bottom: 182px;(svg height) on ".overpass-info-container" to leave the space in bottom? I think there is no other way at this scenario. Also your bottom div also postion:absolute; so why expecting it will leave the space?

Answer (score 2):

In `.overpass-info-container::after`

- Try adding a `display: block`
- Try replacing `position: absolute` with `position: relative`

Those changes should give the `::after` his own space in the HTML.

Comment: Hi @Shaul, thanks for looking into this issue.  However, when I tried applying your suggestion, the svg from  .overpass-info-container::after "disappeared"...

Answer (score 0):

well, I did something simple, still open to suggestions.
I added to each of the children a margin-top attribute, and this took care on things...

```
section.finding-container {
  top: 180px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}
.find-agent {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.agent-profiles {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

thanks for everyone who tried to help...